# GUROBI : Switching between cloud/regular mode

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, gurobi

We have hosted our Gurobi WCF solution as a windows service.

```
                    if (useCloud)
                    {
                        this.logInfo("Environment GRB_LICENSE_FILE: " + System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GRB_LICENSE_FILE"));
                        return new GurobiProblemBuilder(this, new testSolver.solver.gurobi.Net.EnvironmentNet(this.settings.cloudLic, this.settings.cloudPwd));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.logInfo("Environment GRB_LICENSE_FILE: " + System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GRB_LICENSE_FILE"));
                        return new GurobiProblemBuilder(this, new testSolver.solver.gurobi.Net.EnvironmentNet(null));             
                    }
```

In the UI we have provided the option to go to the cloud and handled by the 'useCloud' flag. But the problem is we have to restart the service everytime to toggle between cloud/non-cloud option. Even after setting up the environment variables correctly the service is not able to switch between cloud/non-cloud transparently.

Added on 01-Dec-2015

```
    public EnvironmentNet(string logFileOrNull)
    {
        environment = new GRBEnv(null);        
    }

    public EnvironmentNet(string computeServer, string password)
    {
        // http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/refman/cs_grbenv2.html
        int port = -1; // read from app.config            
        int priority =  0; // read from app.config
        double timeout = -1; // read from app.config

        environment = new GRBEnv(null, computeServer, port, password,    priority, timeout);                            
    }
```

Actually our GurobiProblemBuilder calls the GRBEnv and in turn it calls the GRBEnv(null) or GRBEnv(null,computeServer,port,password,priority,timeout) version depends on the user choice to use cloud or local server. But we're still not able to transparently switch between compute server and local server. This boils down to Gurobi picking up the licence file from GRB_LICENSE_FILE environment variable. Is there any plans to provide a different way of passing the GRB_LICENSE_FILE to Gurobi solver?

Our workaround:
Our approach is when it is cloud use GRB_LICENSE_FILE = gurobi.lic.cloud. If it is non cloud GRB_LICENSE_FILE = gurobi.lic.  May we need to use a common gurobi.lic file and overwrite with compute servers or regular server.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` will return the current value of an environment variable for the current process (e.g. your service process). Process environment variables are only inherited from system environment variables once when the process is started. Therefore the need of a restart is expected behavior.

In general, if you want to use multiple instances of Gurobi with different license files you need to launch seperate processes. In the .NET case changes to the environment variable `GRB_LICENSE_FILE` are only considered before the .NET assembly is loaded, usually at the point when you create a `GRBEnv` object for the first time.

However, in your case there might be an easier solution. You can always create Gurobi Compute Server environments and use your cloud servers (see http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/cs_grbenv2.html).

```
GRBEnv(string logFileName,
       string computeserver,
       int port,
       string password,
       int priority,
       double timeout)
```

You don't need a cloud license file to create Compute Server environments, so simply always use your local license file. Create a model inside a local environment to solve your model on your local computer and create a model inside of a Compute Server environment in cases where you if you want to solve your model in the cloud.